# Exibir dados armazenados no objeto WeakMap

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
var Pessoa = (function(){
    var dadosPrivados = new WeakMap();
    function Pessoa(nome, idade, sexo){
        dadosPrivados.set(this,{nome: nome});
        dadosPrivados.set(this,{idade: idade});
        dadosPrivados.set(this,{sexo: sexo});
    }
    Pessoa.prototype.getDados = function(){
        return dadosPrivados.get((this).nome, (this).idade, (this).sexo);

    };
    return Pessoa;
}());

var rafael = new Pessoa(
    {nome: 'Rafael'},
    {idade: '26'},
    {sexo: 'M'}
);

console.log(rafael.getDados());
```

Ao executar o código, só aparece o nome "Rafael". O erro está no meu `prototype` ou na inserção de dados no objeto `rafael`?

Answer (score 1):

Creio que você está sobrescrevendo os dados com seguidos `dadosPrivados.set`, ou seja, o valor do objeto será o último `dadosPrivados.set` que é referente ao *sexo*. E o objeto `rafael` deveria passar apenas um objeto com os dados (e não 3 separados), já que está usando apenas 1 objeto `WeakMap()`. Veja:

```js
var Pessoa = (function(){
    var dadosPrivados = new WeakMap();
//    function Pessoa(nome, idade, sexo){
    function Pessoa(dados){
        dadosPrivados.set(this,dados);
//        dadosPrivados.set(this,idade);
//        dadosPrivados.set(this,sexo);
    }
    Pessoa.prototype.getDados = function(){
        return dadosPrivados.get(this);

    };
    return Pessoa;
}());

var rafael = new Pessoa (
    {nome: 'Rafael',
    idade: '26',
    sexo: 'M'}
);

console.log(rafael.getDados()); // retorna o objeto inteiro
console.log(rafael.getDados().nome); // retorna o nome
```

Comment: Então bastava colocar todos os dados dentro do mesmo objeto, entendi.
Passei um bom tempo tentando resolver sozinho, muito obrigado!